# Haskell - Maybe arithmetic

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, case-statement, option-type

I have been asked to implement a function which uses the following profile:

```
maybe_divide :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer
```

and responds in the following manner:

```
> maybe_divide (Just 5) (Just 2) 
Just 2
> maybe_divide (Just (-5)) (Just 2) 
Just (-3)
> maybe_divide (Just (-5)) (Just 0) 
Nothing
> maybe_divide Nothing (Just 1) 
Nothing
> maybe_divide (Just 1) Nothing
Nothing
```

I have written the following but it will not compile. Do you guys have any suggestions?

```
maybe_divide :: Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer -> Maybe Integer
maybe_divide x y = case x of
    Just x' -> case y of 
        Just y'
            | y' == 0 -> Nothing  
            | otherwise -> x' `div` y'
    Nothing -> Nothing
```

Comment: What error do you get? Does that give you any clues as to the problem? You might want to think about whether your "otherwise" case returns something of the right type.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: The error is a somewhat misleading "No instance for `Integral (Maybe Integer)`".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Separate from the output type, I'd like to point out a few alternative styles you may prefer for writing this sort of code:

First, you can `case` on multiple expressions by putting them in a tuple:

```
case (x,y) of
    (_      , Just 0) -> Nothing
    (Just x', Just y') -> Just (x' `div` y')
    _ -> Nothing
```

there are a couple different ways to write this using guards, or even the function `Control.Monad.guard`.

```
case (x,y) of
  (Just x', Just y') -> (x' `div` y') <$ guard (y' /= 0)
  _ -> Nothing
```

The second approach would start with a function:

```
safeDiv :: Integer -> Integer -> Maybe Integer
safeDiv x 0 = Nothing
safeDiv x y = Just (x `div` y)
```

Now that you have `safeDiv`, you can lift it into Maybe-wrapped arguments.  It's pretty close to `Applicative` style code, except for an extra layer of `Maybe` in the output.  Fortunately nested monads (e.g. `Maybe (Maybe t)`) are trivial to collapse:

```
maybe_divide x y = join $ safeDiv <$> x <*> y
```

or even

```
maybe_divide = (join .) . liftM2 safeDiv
```

if you're fluent in point-free.

Personally, I would use one of the two tuple-case variants.  But it's fairly common to already have a function like `safeDiv`, in which case the second form can be useful.

Answer (score 7):

You should post the error you are getting, but

```
x' `div` y'
```

has type `Integer` and not `Maybe Integer`.  Perhaps you need to wrap this in a `Just`.

Comment: Thanks you, I appreciate your help. Next time I will post the errors and structure my questions better.

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap the successful result in `Just` here:

```
... | otherwise -> Just (x' `div` y')
```

Answer (score 4):

I think a nice way of doing this is to use the Monad instance for `Maybe`:

```
maybe_divide x y = do
   a <- x
   b <- y
   if b == 0 
     then fail "Division by zero" 
     else return (a/b)
```

This gets rid of most of the tedious checking for `Nothing`s, and cracks on with the main business of checking for divide by zero.

In the Maybe monad, `fail "error message"` actually results in a `Nothing`; the error message is discarded, so I needn't have said `"Division by zero"`, `""` would have done just as well.

In the Maybe monad, `return` means "wrap in a Just".

---

If you don't need to do any error checking, you can use the applicative instance:

```
import Control.Applicative -- at the top of your code

maybe_multiply x y = (*) <$> x <*> y
```

which I think is aethetically pleasing.

This is because for an Applicative instance that matches a Monad, `f <$> x <*> y <*> z` is equivalent to

```
do 
  a <- x
  b <- y
  c <- z
  return $ f a b c
```